# How to pass &rest arguments to another function in emacs lisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have a convinience defun in my init.el to do some logging

```
(defvar log4me::loglevel 5
  "Global loglevel.")

(defun log4me (level logmsg)
  "Log message."
  (interactive)
  (when (>= level log4elisp::loglevel)
    (message logmsg))))
```

It kind of works but somehow i frequently do

```
  (log4me somelevel (format "mymessage with %d" 1))
```

So i found the emacs lisp &rest parameters which i thought i might use like this:

```
(defun log4me (level logmsg &rest formatparams)
  "Log message."
  (interactive)
  (when (<= level log4elisp::loglevel)
    (message (format logmsg formatparams))))

(log4me 3 "Hello %ust!" 1)
```

which resuslts into "Format specifier doesn't match argument type" error since formatparams is actually (1) and not 1.

Is there a nice way to include format parameters into the log4elisp defun and make them arrive in the format function call as "normal" parameters (not a single list)?

Comment: see the function APPLY

Comment: @Rainer Joswig Thanks! I had the feeling that all i needed was a pointer to the right point in the documentation. apply worked well. Do you like to provide a short answer so that i can accept it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you need is [`apply`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Calling-Functions.html):

```
(defun log4me (level logmsg &rest formatparams)
  "Log message."
  (interactive)
  (when (<= level log4elisp::loglevel)
    (apply #'message logmsg formatparams)))
```

Answer (score 0):

`apply` is perfect for functions, but is invalid for function-objects like macros. The following solution is applicable for both functions and macros.

```el
(defun log4me (level logmsg &rest formatparams)
  "Log message."
  (interactive)
  (when (<= level log4elisp::loglevel)
    (eval (append '(message logmsg) formatparams))))
```